# многопользовательское приложение

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Необходимо сделать синхронизацию данных с firebase. У каждого пользователя своя коллекция. Я не понимаю как это реализовать. 
Буду рад любой помощи: ссылки где это описано, ваши комментарии и т.п.))))

Comment: в чем у вас проблема? Не умеете работать с Firebase?

Comment: Вопрос очень общий. Для одного пользователя уже реализовано? Если - да, то нужно описать как. Если нет и проблема в самом сохранении данных в firebase, то вопрос нужно более узко и четко формулировать.

Comment: Да, действительно, вопрос общий оказался. С созданием бд проблем нет. Вопрос в том: пользователь проходит авторизацию, какое правило должно быть, чтобы он только свои записи видел?

Answer (score 0):

В официальной документации (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) это реализовано через  шаблон правил безопасности на основе состояния аутентификации пользователя.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Убедитесь, что uid запрашивающего пользователя совпадает с именем документа
    // пользователя. Подстановочное выражение {userId} делает переменную userId  
    // доступной в правилах.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    // доступ к своим персональным данным
    }

    match /"название каталога"/{document=**} {
       // {document=**} - означает что мы ставим условие для всей
       // последующей иерархии
       allow read, write: if true; // разрешаем читать и добавлять информацию
    }
  }
}
```